# DVD-Player "Simulation"

Tags: dvd, authoring

This may sound like a strange question, but I was wondering if there is software available which can emulate the behaviour of standalone dvd-players. I'm currently debugging a DVD we're creating, and I can't afford to go hopping to my house every time to check.

The reason I'm asking is because the problems just appear on 'some' dvd-players which I cannot predict.

Other option maybe, is there software that can check a VIDEO_TS folder or iso file for errors?

Comment: related question (DVD player emulation): http://superuser.com/questions/129668/how-to-know-if-a-video-file-can-be-played-on-a-dvd-player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I doubt this will get to the heart of the "some players" problem. I always use VLC for stuff like this either the portable version if you don't want to install http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable or the regular version http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Answer (score 1):

[Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) can open a DVD Directory and will play it as if it was a disc in a drive.

`File` -> `Open DVD` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) allows you to select any DVD folder, either from an optical drive or HDD.